# Una Función en MySQL con un parámetro de tipo entero no me funciona

Tags: mysql

Tengo una función sencilla:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO AsambleasGenerales(AfiliadoID, CodigoAfiliado,FechaAsamblea) 
    SELECT AdjudicatariosID, CodigoAdjudicatario,ParamFecha
    FROM Afiliados WHERE Afiliados.Borrado= 0;
END
```

Tiene un parámetro `IN` de tipo fecha y me funciona bien, pero si le agrego un parámetro, específicamente uno de tipo entero no me funciona.

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO AsambleasGenerales(AfiliadoID, CodigoAfiliado,FechaAsamblea, CodigoAsamblea) 
    SELECT AdjudicatariosID, CodigoAdjudicatario,ParamFecha, ParamAsamblea
    FROM Afiliados WHERE Afiliados.Borrado= 0;
END
```

Comment: Pero no das muchos detalles en tu pregunta... que quieres hacer?

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe a qué te refieres con _no funciona_. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Para ayudarte deberíamos poder replicar tu problema. Si no podemos, es que te falta  aportar información :)

Comment: ¿Cómo defines y manejas los parámetros en la función? Es información esencial que no aportas en la pregunta. Pulsa en [edit] y completa la pregunta poniendo el código mínimo y verificable.